# Android: start listener after timing

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization, listener, wait

i've an activity with a ToggleButton that must start (if checked on) or stop (if checked off) a listener.
The problem is that i want to start the listener after a specific time (10 sec for example) but keeping the ToggleButton active and if the user click on it before the timing ending, abort the timing and listener activation.
I'm in confusion with the correct way to do that... do you have any idea?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Timer and TimerTask.
Put the timer on 10 seconds delay.

If the user clicks the button again on these 10 seconds, cancel the Timer.
If not, start the listener.

Note that in order to change UI elements through the TimerTask thread, you will have to use an handler.